# Cypress test fails before values are loaded into formly form

Tags: angular, forms, cypress

I have some really flaky cypress tests currently. At the moment sometimes a test checking the value of a formly input field, after a form gets submitted, fails because cypress checks the value of the field before the Observable providing the values is sending them.

You can see it during the video of the tests, that one frame the test fails saying "Expected value '5' but got value ''" and a few frames later the field has the value 5 in them.

Roughly the code looks like

```
cy.get("field").type("{backspace}" + 5);
cy.get("save").click();
gotoHomeSite();
gotoFormsSite();
cy.get("field").should('have.value', 5);
```

Is there maybe a way to wait for the values to get transmitted when returning back to the settings from the index page?

Comment: There is no video attached to your question.

Comment: Have you tried increasing timeouts? Cypress should() will retry as long as you tell it to.

Comment: @AlapanDas I know sorry, I phrased it poorly. I can't attach a video cause it is work related, my idea was to describe what happened

Comment: @lef How about you add timeouts and then check?

Comment: You should add assertions on each new page and new element you are checking. This can range from `be.visible` and beyond. Also, you may want to add spies on any requests in case the page is waiting for processes to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our problem was on some of the tests we were not waiting for the response of the server correctly.

Increasing the timeout helped but was not the correct solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

A longer timeout may work

```js
cy.get("field", {timeout:10000}).should('have.value', 5)
```